# java compiler environment not working windows

Tags: java, environment-variables, javac

Hi I have set the environment variable for java in windows.
when I type java in cmd, it works,but when I type javac ,it doesn't work saying javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
Doing Path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin works but when I close the command prompt and reopen again same error.
Is there anyway out to set this permanently.

Comment: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: further to @Rohit Jain, once you have set the variable you will need to open a new command window to get the latest environment

Comment: for javac after setting the path ,it works but for that time only and when I close and reopen ,path again needs to be set while java is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can add C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin to your path using the System Control Panel in Windows.

Go to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables...

Find Path, and edit it to add your jdk path.

Comment: that is what I have done and when I type java ,it works in CMD but javac is not working.

Comment: Have you opened a new CMD window after setting the environment variable?

Comment: type `java -version` to see where windows is finding java -- my guess is it's not finding the one in your JDK.

Comment: You can also type `echo %path%` into your command window to see whether the setting you did in the Control Panel "took"

Comment: yeah I opened new cmd window.
java -version also gives the version name.
echo %path% gives the path of java.

Comment: check your `echo %path%` for typos?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply setting the PATH variable of the current session. What you need to do it go to **"Computer/My Computer"**, right click and select **"Properties"**. From there click **"Advanced System Settings"** and then the **"Environment Variables** button. Navigate to the **PATH variable** and append to the end of the string. *Directory paths must be separated by a semi-colon.*

 All of the variables in this section are loaded each time a new process is launched. You can also add a default **CLASSPATH** variable here and include all of your go-to jars.

Comment: yeah I have done that
variable name: java
variable value:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\

Comment: I have mentioned that java is working while javac is not working.

Comment: Typically a system possessing the JDK will have two "Java.exe"s. One in the JRE directory and one in the JDK directory. You are probably referencing the one in the JRE directory which will not contain a compiler.

Comment: are you setting the "java" environment variable, or adding to the "path" environment variable?  You need to do the latter.

Comment: @mmm can you tell us what finally worked for you?  It may save someone else some trouble if they are having the same problem.

Comment: Actually I was adding java as a separate environment variable but now I added that in Path separated by colon(;). So it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have faced this problem and my finding is for Windows 7 adding javac to the "path" environment variable works but for windows 10, you can do anything means Add a new environment variable or update the existing one.